# Mockgoose .POST method failing when insert() is called

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am developing an API but with BDD methods.  My only test that is failing is the mongodb POST method.  Mocha is saying that my insert() property is undefined.  All of my other db functions are passing.  But from what I can find is that I have stated it correct. Here is my route:

```
server.post('/courses/course', function(req, res, next) {
    req.course.insert(req.body, {}, function(err, results) {
        if(err) return next(err);
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

And my test (mocha/CHAI):

```
var id;

    it('should create a new course basic info', function(done) {
        request(server)
            .post('/courses/course')
            .send({
                tdcNumber: 'some wierd number',
                shortTitle: 'Ammo something',
                longTitle: 'Mass Destruction Power'
            })
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                if(err) return done(err);
                expect(err).to.equal(null);
                expect(res.body.length).to.equal(1);
                expect(res.body[0]._id.length).to.equal(24);
                id = res.body[0]._id;
                //expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
                //expect(res.body).to.be.an('object');
                //expect(res.body.course.shortTitle).to.equal('Ammo something');
                //expect(res.body.course.tdcNuymber).to.equal('some wierd number');
                //expect(res.body.course.longTitle).to.equal('Mass Destruction Power');
            })
            done();
    });
```

I am sure that its a stupid noobie mistake.  I have my project up on github https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/apiMockgoose

so where is it??

tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong method used.  Should have used .'save' as in the following:

```
courseName.save(function(err) {
        if(err) res.send(err);
        res.json({message: 'A new course name added to the library shelves!', data: courseName});
    });
```

new project with sample code is https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/hermes-cardCatalog/commit/a675a322589cd1857b628ccf3122a18ae4c748cf